# recursive algorithm to find divisors, without the use of loops

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to find an algorithm to print all the divisors of n (including 1 and n), but it can only be recursive with 1 input and no loops at all. I tried toying with prime numbers and maybe looking for a pattern but I can't seem to find a way without a `for` or a `while`. So the declaration of the function has to be `void divisors( int n )` and it needs to be recursive. I don't want a full code since it is an assignment, I'm more looking for a hint, or a perspective that i might be missing

Comment: How would you write it if you were allowed to use loops?

Comment: This problem is not very appropriate to be solved with recursion. Recursion is good when each step is "reducing" the problem to a smaller problem, which is then is solved in a similar manner. It is not really the case here. You are going to simulate a loop and that's it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica if i could use a loop or at least send an index ```i``` i would at least be able to go through all numbers between 1 and n using the index. if i find that the nymber is divisible by 2, i would only need to check the the numbers between 2 and n/2, ill keep making the search range smaller. but since i cant use and index i dont know how to make it work

Comment: BTW, I don't see how this can be done with `void divisors( int n )` signature, unless it is a wrapper to another recursive function with more parameters.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is there a way for me to simulate a loop without the need of a second input that is an index or counter of sorts? i feel like its obvious and im just not getting it...

Comment: @EugeneSh. im allowed to make side functions, but no loops, this is the signature given though

Comment: No, you need a second input. This is why I said this can be a wrapper function for the recursive one with two inputs.

Comment: A recursive solution can be appropriate for prime factors though, due to the fact division of a number `n` by it's prime factor `p` *does* reduce the problem to finding prime factors of `n/p`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But how do you find `p` without a loop?

Comment: @Barmar That's a side problem. I'm just saying that `PrimeFactors(n) = [p, PrimeFactors(n/p)]` is a proper recursion

Comment: Make the one input a pointer to all the data you want.

Comment: @Eric: I think she's stuck with the function signature as stated in the OP.

Comment: @mzimmers: Maybe, but OP does not say the problem specification dictates that signature. Rather, they say “So the declaration of the function has to be…,” suggesting that signature is their own conclusion from the one-input requirement. If so, it is not correct; a requirement that there be one input admits the possibility of other signatures.

Comment: Suppose the routine is passed a number n and should print all the divisors of n. Given that the routine must be recursive, it might call itself with some factor of n, say f. That recursive call will print all the factors of f. Then the call that was passed n must otherwise print all the factors of n that are not also factors of f, which I will call the extra factors. Perhaps it might do this with its own code or it might do it with recursive calls. However, a problem is that the number of such factors varies. For example, if n is 14 and f is 7, there are two extra factors, 2 and 14…

Comment: … However, if n is 30 and f is 15, there are four extra factors, 2, 6, 10, and 30. There can be arbitrarily many extra factors. This implies the routine cannot do a fixed amount of printing; it must use some loop. But using a loop, other than recursion, is prohibited. Also, printing the extra factors cannot be done by a recursive call to the routine, since 1 is a factor of any positive integer, so any recursive call must print 1; it cannot be limited to 2, 6, 10, and 30. Therefore, if a no-loop recursive solution is possible, it cannot be accomplished by passing only the number to be factored.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I can think of at least 2 different solutions :)

Comment: If you are allowed to use `static` variables in your function, then the solution becomes extremely easy.

Answer (score 1):

As documented by @CraigEstey, the the classic recursive approach would require a second argument. Since the prototype is fixed, you need another way to keep track the current divisor. You can:

- use a global variable
- use a local static variable.
- use part of the argument for the divisor, drastically reducing the range of values for the initial call.

This is not very elegant but does not seem to break the rules.

Here is an example with a thread local `static` variable:

> ```
> void divisors(int n) {
>     static _Thread_local int p = 0;
>     if (p++ == 0) {
>         printf("divisors of %d:", n);
>     }
>     if (p > n) {
>         printf("\n");
>         p = 0;
>         return;
>     }
>     if (n % p == 0) {
>         printf(" %d", p);
>     }
>     divisors(n);
> }
> ```

If you are willing to abuse the rules a bit more, here is an even simpler one that meets the criteria:

- conforming prototype `void divisors(int n)`
- no `for` or `while` loops
- use of recursion

> ```
> void divisors(int n) {
>     int p = 1;
>     if (n <= 0) return;
>     printf("divisors of %d:", n);
>   next:
>     if (n % p == 0) printf(" %d", p);
>     if (p++ < n) goto next;
>     printf("\n");
>     divisors(0);  // dummy recursive call
> }
> ```

Comment: Since the computation runs to completion, there is nothing particularly ugly about this approach.

Comment: @jxh: indeed, I rephrased the answer... how about rewarding creativity?

Comment: You may be able to remove the `goto` by using `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

Comment: @jxh: creativity indeed! hiding a loop with `setjmp()`/`longjmp()`, sounds good :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand:

- The declaration of the function has to be `void divisors( int n )`
- It needs to be recursive
- No <s>capes</s> loops

One solution is to use indirect recursion. This allows a helper function to be implemented to maintain state in an extra parameter, but the helper function can call upon `divisors()`. In so doing, it is recursively called.

So, for example, you could use signed values to indicate `divisors()` should print the negative value as a divisor.

> ```
> void divisors (int n) {
>     if (n > 0) {
>         printf("divisors of %d:", n);
>         divisors2(n, 1);
>     }
>     else if (n < 0) printf(" %d", -n);
>     else printf("\n");
> }
> ```

And the recursive `divisors2()` would call `divisors()` with a negative parameter to print a found divisor.

> ```
> void divisors2 (int n, int p) {
>     if (p > n) {
>         divisors(0);
>         return;
>     }
>     if (!(n % p)) divisors(-p);
>     divisors2(n, ++p);
> }
> ```

Comment: More amazing tricks to fit the rules :)

Answer (score 0):

This can *not* be done with a single argument.

I realized this (as did others)

Eric came up with the rationale/proof in the comments, so I'll summarize them here:

> Maybe, but OP does not say the problem specification dictates that signature. Rather, they say “So the declaration of the function has to be…,” suggesting that signature is their own conclusion from the one-input requirement. If so, it is not correct; a requirement that there be one input admits the possibility of other signatures. –
> Eric Postpischil

> Suppose the routine is passed a number n and should print all the divisors of n. Given that the routine must be recursive, it might call itself with some factor of n, say f. That recursive call will print all the factors of f. Then the call that was passed n must otherwise print all the factors of n that are not also factors of f, which I will call the extra factors. Perhaps it might do this with its own code or it might do it with recursive calls. However, a problem is that the number of such factors varies. For example, if n is 14 and f is 7, there are two extra factors, 2 and 14… –
> Eric Postpischil

> … However, if n is 30 and f is 15, there are four extra factors, 2, 6, 10, and 30. There can be arbitrarily many extra factors. This implies the routine cannot do a fixed amount of printing; it must use some loop. But using a loop, other than recursion, is prohibited. Also, printing the extra factors cannot be done by a recursive call to the routine, since 1 is a factor of any positive integer, so any recursive call must print 1; it cannot be limited to 2, 6, 10, and 30. **Therefore, if a no-loop recursive solution is possible, it *cannot* be accomplished by passing *only* the number to be factored.** –
> Eric Postpischil

---

From the above:

So, while we need:

```
void divisors(int n)
```

This, does *not* preclude a helper function (e.g.)

```
void divrec(int n,int f)
```

Where `f` is the current divisor/factor to test.

Printing `1` and `n` as factors has to be special cased.

But, after that, `divrec` can call itself recursively, starting with `divisors` calling with: `divrec(n,2)`. If crafted carefully, the compiler optimizer will do "tail recursion" so we don't blow up the stack.

The actual function is so simple, it's hard to "hint" at it without just actually showing it, but:

1. If `f > n`, stop/return.
2. If `n` *is* divisible by `f`, then print `f` and divide `n` by `f`.
3. Otherwise, increase `f` by 1.
4. recursively call `divrec` with the updated `n` and `f` values.

IMO, the resulting C code is easier to understand than the pseudocode description here.

---

Here is the sample code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef long long num;

#define DIVME(_expr) \
    do { \
        printf("EXPR: " #_expr "\n"); \
        divisors((num) _expr); \
    } while (0)

void
prt(num f)
{

    printf(" %lld",f);
}

void
divrec(num n,num f)
// n -- remaining number
// f -- current factor to try
{

    // at this point, we've "looped" f all the way from 2 to n
    if (f > n)
        return;

    // got a factor:
    // (1) print it
    // (2) reduce the number down
    // (e.g.) number divisible by 2 -- next try is (n / 2,2)
    if ((n % f) == 0) {
        prt(f);
        n /= f;
    }

    // number is _not_ divisible by current factor -- increase the factor by 1
    // (e.g.) number is _not_ divisible by 2 -- next try is (n,3)
    else
        f += 1;

    // ensure "tail recursion" so we do _not_ blow up the stack
    // (with optimization)
    // NOTE: on my system, this generates an internal loop in the asm insts
    // generated
    divrec(n,f);
}

void
divisors(num n)
{

    // special case for n/1:
    prt(1);
    prt(n);
    printf("\n");

    divrec(n,2);
    printf("\n");
}

int
main(void)
{

    DIVME(2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 3 * 7 * 13 * 13);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
EXPR: 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 3 * 7 * 13 * 13
 1 37462588393230
 2 3 3 5 7 7 11 13 13 13 17 23 29 31
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> How about lateral thinking? –
> chqrlie

Hahaha ... Well, if you insist ... :-)

I *had* considered [some of] the tricks used by other answers but decided against them because using a segmented number, global variable, or "indirect" recursion were [somewhat] "cheating". I considered my approach to be the least "cheating", but now, it has a similar "smell" to it :-)

So, maybe it's time to rethink and clarify the problem statement ...

From OP's first sentence:

> I'm trying to find an algorithm to print all the *divisors* of n (including 1 and n), but it can only be recursive with 1 input and no loops at all.

IMO, this is the problem statement.

Here is OP's second sentence:

> I tried toying with prime numbers and maybe looking for a pattern but I can't seem to find a way without a `for` or a `while`

IMO, this is [just] OP's solution/interpretation of the problem.

So, there are *two* definitions of *divisor*:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)

(1) seems to be what everybody is [*erroneously* :-)] using.

But, from (2), for division, *divisor* is just any [and all] number(s) than can divide a given number (i.e.):

```
quotient + remainder = dividend / divisor
```

With that second definition in mind, the divisors of a given number `n` are any and *all* numbers between `1` and `n` (inclusive), regardless of remainder.

So, here's the updated code:

```
void prt(int n);

void
divisors(int n)
// n -- remaining number
{

    // at this point, we've "looped" all the way from n to 1
    if (n < 1)
        return;

    prt(n);

    divisors(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: How about lateral thinking?

Comment: @chqrlie Well, I've just come up with a solution that isn't covered by any of the prior answers. So, have a look. It's definitely "lateral" :-)

Comment: Original idea, but by the same logic, shouldn't any non zero integer be considered a *divisor*?

Answer (score 0):

**updated**

Assuming you can only use an int parameter as in:

`void divisors(int n)`

Cheat and use the upper bits of the parameter, `n` passed in as a way to stash the current divisor. There's some reasonable assumptions: 2's complement, 8-bit bytes, and an int is at least 32-bit wide. But that's pretty much universal these days.

For any pair of factors for `n`, `x` and `y` with `x<y`, then `x` will be at most `sqrt(n)`.  It takes half the number of bits to hold the square root of a number.  So 1/3 of our bits for the divisor and the other 2/3 of our bits for the value we are attempting to factor.

The compromise if that on a 32-bit int, the range is limited to 21-bits, or `0 <= n <= 2097151`

```
void divisors(int n)
{
    unsigned int un = (unsigned int) n;
    size_t width = sizeof(n) * 8;

    // we can use up to 1/3 of our bits to hold the divisor
    size_t valueprecision = (width * 2)/3;
    size_t divprecision = width-valueprecision;
    

    unsigned int divisor = un >> valueprecision;
    unsigned int mask = (unsigned int)(-1);
    mask = mask >> divprecision;

    unsigned int value = un & mask;

    if (divisor == 0)
    {
        divisor = 1;
    }

    if (value % divisor == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", divisor);
        if (divisor != (value/divisor))
        {
            printf("%d\n", value / divisor);
        }
    }

    divisor++;

    // the stopping point is when divisor > sqrt(value), or divisor*divsor > value
    if ((divisor * divisor) > value)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    un = (divisor << valueprecision) | value;
    divisors(un);
}
```

Invoking `divisors(2097151)` prints:

```
1
2097151
7
299593
49
42799
127
16513
337
6223
889
2359
```

Comment: *But I suspect stack overflow will occur for much sooner than that as `n` approaches 1000.* ...  Not if your optimizing compiler detects tail recursion.

Comment: ooh... you are probably right.  I only tested on DEBUG. After I wrote that statement, I modified the code above to stop when `divisor*divisor > value`, so it would do at most 256 recursions... which opens it up to extending out the available integer range even further.

Comment: @chqrlie - Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: Given how you split the bits, `divprecision` is `10` on 32-bit systems and the function can recurse as much as 1023 times. Note as a matter of fact that contrary to your example, argument values between `1048576` and `4194303` cause an infinite recursion and repeating output. You should round `divprecision`up as `divprecision = (width + 2) / 3` to split the 32 bits as 11 divisor bits and 21 value bits.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I went on and corrected that. I'm done with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my second attempt. An even bigger hack.**

Since this is "anything goes" including risking **undefined behavior**, I think it's fair game for this problem.

This solution borrows unclaimed stack memory above the current function call to stash the current "divisor" variable about 4k higher in the stack. In subsequent recursions, it's unlikely this memory gets claimed by the recursion, but not so high where the memory isn't available.

It does use a loop - but only to find the divisor in the stack

**Production ready?** - no!

**Safe and free from undefined behavior?** - definitely not!

**What about the stack guard technology in modern compilers?** - The compiler may have inserted tamper protection on the data below the current stack pointer, but does not appear to guard the unused area above the stack pointer.

**What about compiler optimizations that would break the assumptions about the stack?** The compiler is free to ruin this solution with any optimization it wants. I found a `printf` hack that seems to thwart gcc doing tail recursion optimizations.

**Portable** - Lol. I can't claim it's truly portable when it's relying on undefined behavior. But it works on optimized Visual C++, Clang, and gcc.

[Watch it run here](https://cplayground.com/?p=dogfish-ant-axolotl)

```
void divisors(int n)
{
    // scan upward in the stack by up to looking for the guard bytes that proceed the
    // divisor variable we are stashing. If not found, assume 0

    if (n < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    int* stackptr = &n;
    const int stashoffset = 1000;
    int* ptr1 = stackptr - stashoffset;
    int* ptr2 = ptr1 + 1;
    int divisor = 0;

    printf("", &n); // this thwarts gcc optimizations

    // go look for where a previous recursion may have hid the divisor
    for (int i = 0; i < stashoffset; i++)
    {
        if ((*ptr1 == 0xdeadbeef) && (*ptr2 == 0xdeadbeef))
        {
            divisor = ptr2[1];
            *ptr1 = 0;
            *ptr2 = 0;
            break;
        }
        ptr1++;
        ptr2++;
    }

    divisor++;

    if (n % divisor == 0)
    {
        printf("%d, %d\n", divisor, n / divisor);
    }

    if ((divisor * divisor) >= n)
    {
        return;
    }

    // stash the divisor way up there in the stack and put
    // some dead beef around it to it can be discovered in the next recursion
    ptr1 = stackptr - stashoffset;
    ptr2 = ptr1 + 1;
    *ptr1 = 0xdeadbeef;
    *ptr2 = 0xdeadbeef;
    ptr2[1] = divisor;

    divisors(n); // recurse here
}
```