# check if number is prime using recursion with only one parameter in c language

Tags: c, function, recursion, primes

I've got a task in my lesson to write a function that will check if a number is prime, it will return 1 if it is and 0 if it is not and all of that to do recursively. the function will look like that :int isPrime(int num);
I've tried everything and searched everywhere and came to the conclusion that it's possible only with static int which I did not learn yet so can't use it or with two parameters.
does anyone know if there is a way to solve it with only one parameter ad no static int?
thanks.

Comment: `static int IsPrime(int n) { if (n < 2) return 0; for (int d = 2; d*d <= n; ++d) if (n % d == 0) return 0; /* Look, recursion! */ return !IsPrime(1); }`

Comment: How big is the number? There's probably lots of unused bits in that single parameter you could totally use for other things.

Comment: See the recent similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061248/recursive-algorithm-to-find-divisors-without-the-use-of-loops

Comment: include `stdbool.h` and use `bool isPrime(int num)` and return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a trick question: you are supposed to use recursion, but unless you are barred from using loops, a classic solution with a `for` loop can be made to comply with the recursion requirement.

Here is a function `isPrime` that has a single argument and uses a classic loop and recursion to test prime divisors:

```
int isPrime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 0;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return n == 2;
    for (int p = 3; p * p <= n; p += 2) {
         if (isPrime(p) && n % p == 0)
             return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The above code only performs the modulo operation for prime divisors. It is a false optimisation because it is actually more costly to determine if `p` is prime with a recursive call than to compute `n % p`.

Comment: How is that the answer? If you remove the recursive call the function still works, it's even faster.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: sure, it is quite common to optimize code by simply removing redundant or useless code :) If you have a better solution with recursion, I am curious to see it.  This silly answer to a trick question can prompt a discussion about premature optimisation, which might be the purpose.

Comment: I don't think the question makes any sense. You can't do it without cheating: static variable, global variable, putting multiple numbers into the int, binding in a lambda. You need something to hold a second argument to turn your for loop into a recursion.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: I agree, and this question is close to a recent duplicate... Maybe the teacher's agenda is to deter students from using recursion to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution to this questionable assignment. It contains only functions taking one int argument and uses recursion and no loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<bool(int)> isPrime(int x) {
    return [x](int p) {
        if (x <= 2) return true;
        return (p % (x - 1) != 0) && (isPrime(x - 1)(p));
    };
}

int main() {
    if (isPrime(19)(19)) std::cout << "is prime" << std::endl;
}
```